# IIS backup is backing up old history not new live data from IIS (All sites and Pools not new)

Tags: iis, backup, application-pools

Windows 2016 Core Servers / IIS10
**==IMPORTANT==**
The backup seems to be backing up OLD data.
It seems that it is picking up on history instead of backing up the LIVE data.
This will explain WHY it is not getting all the sites and pools during the backup of either of the two methods below.

Looking in the
C:\Windows\System32\InetSrv\config
Folder, I see that all the files here are from 2020, so it backs this information up.
I also looked in
C:\Inetpub\history
These files are identical to the ones above as well.
Why is it not showing updated files in this location?

Also, from what I read here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641621/applicationhost-config-not-showing-changes), the 64-bit version of the file is not being seen.
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv
When viewing this location, there are NO files here.
So, what am I missing?

Using the CMD line

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add backup "WebCore-01 - 1-261-2023"
```

Using the PS

```
backup-WebConfiguration -Name "WebCore-01 - 1-261-2023"
```

I never really noticed this issue in the past until I brought in new webcore servers and added them into the IIS Server Farm and synced them with the primary server, and noticed that all other web servers were working, but two sites were not working on the two new VM servers. I chased down the issue, or one of the issues was the BINDINGS were all from months ago. As several bindings were removed back in mid-summer of 2022, but yet that is the time period being backed up during the above two mentioned methods.

Thank you.
Wayne

Comment: SysWOW64 is for *32-bit* binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
If anyone has this issue while running a Web Farm with IIS, and you are running Shared config files, the primary server will have its config files stored in the location you designated during the Shared Config setup.

In my case, there located here
G:\IIS_Config

This was annoying, now I need to share this location with the two new servers, and we are good to go.